# dxf_input.py returns ZeroDivisionError when opening dxf file

Tags: python, inkscape, dxf

I have [a dxf file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/daebc61b235e8a71579d5ce1b8539acd20190613152420/0ce913b1fb822a3aa630a24c5c91714320190613152420/433437) which I have exported from SolidWorks. I want to use Inkscape to open them up, modify them and send for laser cutting. However, when I open them I get this error:

```
Inkscape has received additional data from the
script executed. The script did not return an error,
but this may indicate the result will not be as expected
```

and then

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dxf_input.py", line 443, in <module>
w = 90.0/25.4*vals[groups['370']][0]/00.0
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

I opened the file in other software like LibreCAD and it works just fine. Even more strange the files open just fine on macOS and other Windows machines. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software multiple times but it did not help either.

My environment is:

- Inkscape Inkscape 0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14) installed through Chocolatey
- Windows 10 Version 1809

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that the parser hadn't accounted for the possibility of the value of DXF group 370 being zero (since a lineweight of zero is valid) however, in [this version](https://inkscape.gitlab.io/inkscape/doxygen-extensions/dxf__input_8py_source.html) of `dxf_input.py` there is a check for whether DXF group 370 (lineweight) is zero prior to division:

```
if vals[groups['370']]:                 # Common Lineweight
    if vals[groups['370']][0] > 0:      # <-------------------- HERE
        w = 96.0/25.4*vals[groups['370']][0]/100.0
        if w < 0.5:
            w = 0.5
```

And so I don't believe this is the issue.

I then observed that it's odd that the value of `100.0` from the above is showing as `0.00` in your traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dxf_input.py", line 443, in <module>
w = 90.0/25.4*vals[groups['370']][0]/00.0 # <-------------------- This is 100.0 in the code
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Therefore, perhaps it's possible that this could be a typo introduced in the preview release v0.92.4, as in v0.91 of `dxf_input.py` I can confirm that this line appears as:

```
w = 90.0/25.4*vals[groups['370']][0]/100.0
```

To verify whether this is the cause of the error, you can view the source of `dxf_input.py` by going to `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions` and opening the file in an appropriate code editor, such as Notepad++.

Search for `w = 90.0/25.4` in the source code and check that the division is by `100.0` instead of `00.0`.

Comment: This, if true, would be very strange because I keep the exact same version of Inkscape on four different Windows computers with Chocolatey. They are all the same version, and only one of them shows this issue. I just tested this on my personal Windows laptop, and the `dxf_input.py` seems to be fine. I will test it on the work computer tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that an older version of dxf_input extension, including the `dxf_input.py` and `dxf_input.inx` were installed in the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Inkscape\extensions` folder. As a result, no matter how many times I uninstalled and reinstalled Inkscape the error persisted. That older version as noted by Lee in the other answer here had the line

```
w = 90.0/25.4*vals[groups['370']][0]/00.0
```

deleting these files resolved the issue. I don't recall when and where I installed these files from, otherwise, I would go and report an issue or put a PR to fix this bug.

Comment: Thank you for confirming; though, this should really have been a comment on my answer to avoid duplication.

Comment: @LeeMac I wasn't quite sure if I should edit your post or leave a comment or add a P.S. to my post. So I posted a new answer anyway. I appreciate your support.

Comment: No problem; If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution, so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks.